# How to fix error changing root password with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having trouble changing the root password for mySql (mariadb).  I am using the standard command:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password "$MYSQLROOTPWD"
```

and the result is this:

```
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
server version for the right syntax to use near '() IDENTIFIED 
BY 'MyNewPassword'' at line 1'
```

It is a new install of Fedora34 and all I do is start the mariadb service and then try to set the password.  I verified that this is the correct command and I am at a loss as to why it does not work.

O/S - Fedora 34 - 5.12.8-300.fc34.x86_64

DB  - mariadb.x86_64 - 3:10.5.10-1.fc34

Comment: subtle differences http://www.sesan.gob.gt/dashboard/docs/reset-mysql-password.html

Comment: You say you want to CHANGE the password rather than SET the password `mysqladmin --user=root --password=oldpwd password "newpwd"`

Comment: I am sorry - I was changing the password from the default null.  You are correct I am setting an initial password.  Using --user=root returns the same error.

Comment: Try no space between `-u` and `root` like `-uroot`

Comment: I get the same error.  The regular syntax works on Fedora 32 (older version of mariadb), not sure why the same thing does not work here.